# Accessing TextFormField controller within an abstract class

Tags: flutter

I'm wondering if there is any way to access the controller outside the main stateful widget.

e.g, I created an abstract class to separate the overflow of a stateful class.

The issue that I want to use the value of the text within the widget and as far as I know it can be accessed through the **some_controller.text**

Any advice?

```
abstract class TextFieldWidget {
TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
 static Widget emailTextFeild() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200]))),
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.orange[100], width: 2)),
            floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
            labelText: "Email",
            prefixIcon: Icon(
              Icons.person,
              color: Colors.blueAccent[100],
            ),
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            border: InputBorder.none),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the controller in whole class?

You can do this by using it outside like below.

```
TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
```

And then,

```
abstract class TextFieldWidget {
  static Widget emailTextFeild(email) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200]))),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: email,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.orange[100], width: 2)),
            floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
            labelText: "Email",
            prefixIcon: Icon(
              Icons.person,
              color: Colors.blueAccent[100],
            ),
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            border: InputBorder.none),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And you call the class in the main class like below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: TextFieldWidget.emailTextFeild(_emailController),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```